# cannot insert variable with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

im having a problem inserting some variables into my database, here's my code.

```
  preg_match('/Tel\. P(.)liza :(.*?)Localidad/s', $a->output(), $tel);
  echo "Tel. Poliza: " . $tel[2] . "<br><br>";
  $tel = $tel[2];

  preg_match('/Tel\. Expt :(.*?)D\.P\./s', $a->output(), $tel1);
  $tel1 = $tel1[1];
  preg_match_all('/\\b[0-9]{9}\\b/s', $tel1, $tel2);
  $tel2 = implode(" / ", $tel2[0]);
  echo "Tel. Expt: " . $tel2 . "<br><br>";

  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=something', 'something', 'something');

  $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (tel poliza, tel expt) VALUES ( ? , ? )";
  $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute(array ($tel, $tel2));
```

i can echo this variables(they are just numbers from a pdf file) but when i run the sql query nothing is inserted into the db. i have tried this with other variables in my code and they get inserted but when i had this 2 to the query nothing is inserted at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table column names have spaces in then therefore you have to put them in back quotes

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (`tel poliza`, `tel expt`) VALUES ( ? , ? )";
```